# Forward to login page instead of redirect in Spring Security

Tags: redirect, spring-security, forward

Using Spring Security, how can I forward (server-side redirect) to login page instead of redirect to it?

Same question for session management and invalid session url.

Comment: Why do you want to do it? Probably a bad idea to move away from Post-Redirect-Get pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @holmis83 that it is not a good idea to switch from redirect to forward.

Spring Security [API documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint.html) indicates that this can be done by using the `setUseForward` method.  You can instantiate a `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint` in your configuration, set forward to `true` and the pass this instance to the Spring Security HTTP element.

Comment: How can I do the same for `session-invalid-url`?

Comment: You will have to look through the API documentation for the respective components that handle those events.  In almost all cases, Spring Security classes are non-final so even if the code out there does not help, one can extend the default classes and pass them to the configuration, once the right class has been identified.